# Moving tikz node scales coordinates in scope

Tags: tikz-pgf, bounding-box

I was looking for a way to overlay an image with an grid. I found this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz), which allows me to get an evenly sized grid over an arbitrary sized image (see first figure attached). Very nice!

However, if I use a outer bounding box, the grid coordinates are scaled, when moving the image node (see second figure attached).

I found that this effect occurs, as soon as the node is moved. Additionally the grid completely disappears, as soon as the anchor is changed to center (see third figure attached)

**Edit:**
It seems like I missunderstood what scope does. It want to reference the image-node only.
Ultimatively I want to overlay an image with an grid. The cells in the grid should all have the same size. I then want to place this image node and grid with respect to some other node

```
    \documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
    
    \begin{document}
    
    %%% Fig 1
    % first figure, as found in the answer mentioned
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      % include image as node
      \node[anchor=south west, inner sep=0, minimum height=9, minimum width=12] (image1)  at  (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{some_image.jpg}};
      
      % grid over the image using scope
      \begin{scope}[x={(image1.south east)},y={(image1.north west)}]
        \draw[thick, red,xstep=.1,ystep=.1] (0,0)  grid (1,1);
      \end{scope}
    
      % Some title
      \node[anchor=south west]  at  (image1.north west) {\Large This works!};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    %%% Fig 2
    % outer boundingbox m does funny stuff inside the scope
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      % the boundingbox for the image
      \useasboundingbox[fill=gray!20] (0, 0)  rectangle  (12,9);
    
      % image node as before, but node now at some non-origin coordinates
      \node[anchor=south west, inner sep=0] (image2)  at  (.5, .6) {\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{some_image.jpg}};
    
      % scopas before
      \begin{scope}[x={(image2.south east)},y={(image2.north west)}]
        \draw[thick,red, xstep=.1,ystep=.1] (0,0)  grid (1,1);
      \end{scope}
    
      % Some title
      \node[anchor=south west]  at  (image2.north west) {\Large This doesn't};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    
    %%% Fig 3
    % grid is gone completly
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      % Boundingbox around center (Grid is gone no matter if there is a bounding box or not)
      \useasboundingbox[fill=gray!20] (-6, -4.5)  rectangle  (6, 4.5);
    
      % include image as node
      \node[anchor=center, inner sep=0] (image3)  at  (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{some_image.jpg}};
      
      % grid over the image using scope
      \begin{scope}[x={(image3.south east)}, y={(image3.north west)}]
        \draw[thick, red,xstep=.1,ystep=.1] (0,0)  grid (1,1);
      \end{scope}
    
      % Some title
      \node[anchor=south west]  at  (image3.north west) {\Large Grid is gone completly};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    \end{document}
```

[image: Output of minimum working example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### UPDATE

I don't think `grid` is the right way to annotate the image. Cauze `grid` is the high level command of `\pgfpathgrid` with which

> Conceptually, **the origin is part of the grid** and the grid is clipped to the rectangle specified by two points. However, no clipping occurs (this command just adds parts to the
> current path) and the points where the lines enter and leave the “clipping area” are computed and used
> to add simple lines to the current path.

I define a new coordinate system `img cs` to help the work.
[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{xparse}
\makeatletter
\newif\ifxtick@rotate
\tikzset{
  img/.cd,
  x/.store in=\img@x,
  y/.store in=\img@y,
  node/.store in=\img@node,
}
\tikzdeclarecoordinatesystem{img}
{%
  \tikzset{img/.cd,#1}%
  \tikz@scan@one@point\pgf@process(\img@node.south west)
  \pgf@xa=\pgf@x
  \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
  \tikz@scan@one@point\pgf@process(\img@node.north east)
  \pgfmathparse{(1-(\img@x))*\pgf@xa+(\img@x)*\pgf@x}
  \pgf@x=\pgfmathresult pt
  \pgfmathparse{(1-(\img@y))*\pgf@ya+(\img@y)*\pgf@y}
  \pgf@y=\pgfmathresult pt
}%
\NewDocumentCommand {\picgrid} {O{10} O{10} D(){} O{}} {
  \pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=2}
  \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \x using \i/#1] in {0,...,#1}
  \draw[#4]
    (img cs:node=#3, x=\x, y=0)
    node[rotate=-90, anchor=west] {\pgfmathprintnumber{\x}}
    -- (img cs:node=#3, x=\x, y=1);
  \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \y using \i/#2] in {0,...,#2}
  \draw[#4]
    (img cs:node=#3, y=\y, x=0)
    node[left] {\pgfmathprintnumber{\y}}
    -- (img cs:node=#3, y=\y, x=1);
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[anchor=south west, inner sep=0] (a)  at  (.5, .6) {\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{example-image}};
  \picgrid[20][20](a)[red, thick]
  \draw[thick, img/node=a] (img cs:x=.1, y=.6) --
    node[sloped, above] {from (.1, .6) to (.85, .95)}
    (img cs:x=.85, y=.95);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### old answer

`<coord-1> grid <coord-2>` means draw grid on the rectangle which is specified by `<coord-1>` and `<coord-2>`. Let's see where `<coord-1>` -- `(0, 0)` and `<coord-2>` -- `(1, 1)` actually lay on your second picture:
[image]

As you see, there is nothing wrong.

So what's wrong with your third picture? Let's draw `x unit vector` and `y unit vector` of your scope:
Ahha, `x = -y`, which means any coordinate like `(i, i)` actually is `(0, 0)`. So `(0, 0) grid (0, 0)` does nothing.
[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, fit}
\usetikzlibrary {arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
  direct/.style={
    line width=1pt,
    arrows={-Stealth[length=3mm, width=3mm, #1]}
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[anchor=south west, inner sep=0] (image2)  at  (.5, .6) {\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{example-image}};

  \begin{scope}[x={(image2.south east)},y={(image2.north west)}]
    \draw[direct, green] (0, 0) -- (1, 1);
    \draw[thick,red, opacity=0.5, xstep=.1,ystep=.1] (0,0)  grid (1,1);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[anchor=center, inner sep=0] (image3)  at  (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{example-image}};
  % show x, y vector
  \draw[direct, red] (0, 0) -- (image3.south east) node [red, right] {$y$};
  \draw[direct, blue] (0, 0) -- (image3.north west) node [blue, left] {$x$};
  \begin{scope}[x={(image3.south east)}, y={(image3.north west)}]
    \draw[direct, green] (0, 0) -- (1, 1);
    \draw[thick,red, opacity=0.5, xstep=.1,ystep=.1] (0,0)  grid (1,1);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Seemingly I did not quite understand what scope is doing.

From your example I see that scope references/masks/shadows the whole TikZ image. But how can I scope the image node with the includegraphics?

Comment: I don't quite understand what do you want (may be drawing grid on part of image?), could you provide an example image?

Comment: Considering `\node[anchor=south west, inner sep=0] (image2)  at  (.5, .6) {\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{example-image}};`
If the `at  (.5, .6)` is dropped, so that we end up with
`\node[anchor=south west, inner sep=0] (image2) {\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{example-image}};`

The arrow starts at the `south west` and ends at `north east` of the image node. The coordinates `(0,0)` and `(1,1)` within the scope are equal to the corners of the image node.

With `at (.5, .6)` this is not the case any more. I want this, so that I can evenly divide the image with `xstep`

Comment: I use another way@rikisa

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I was looking for! I falsely assumed that scope creates the new coordinate system for me. Thanks again!